# Python: accessing DLL function using ctypes -- access by function *name* fails

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, attributeerror

`myPythonClient` (below) wants to invoke a `ringBell` function (loaded from a DLL using `ctypes`).  However, attempting to access `ringBell` via its *name* results in an `AttributeError`. Why?

`RingBell.h` contains

```
namespace MyNamespace
    {
    class MyClass
        {
        public:
            static __declspec(dllexport) int ringBell ( void ) ;
        } ;
    }
```

`RingBell.cpp` contains

```
#include <iostream>
#include "RingBell.h"
namespace MyNamespace
    {
    int __cdecl MyClass::ringBell ( void )
        {
        std::cout << "\a" ;
        return 0 ;
        }
    }
```

`myPythonClient.py` contains

```
from ctypes import *
cdll.RingBell[1]() # this invocation works fine
cdll.RingBell.ringBell() # however, this invocation errors out
# AttributeError: function 'ringBell' not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps because the C++ name is mangled by the compiler and not exported from the DLL as `RingBell`. Have you checked that it appears in the exported names exactly like that?

Comment: You were correct.
I used the following to discover the "mangled" name:
link.exe /dump /exports RingBell.dll
and discovered that, in the DLL, the name of the function was
"?ringBell@MyClass@MyNamespace@@SAHXZ".

Thank you!

Comment: I'll also mention that I used Python's getattr function to obtain a reference to the ringBell function:
myRingBellFunction = getattr(cdll.RingBell, "?ringBell@MyClass@MyNamespace@@SAHXZ")
myRingBellFunction() # invoke the function again

Answer (score 13):

Your C++ compiler is mangling the names of all externally visible objects to reflect (as well as their underlying names) their namespaces, classes, and signatures (that's how overloading becomes possible).

In order to avoid this mangling, you need an `extern "C"` on externally visible names that  you want to be visible from non-C++ code (and therefore such names cannot be overloaded, nor in C++ standard can they be inline, within namespaces, or within classes, though some C++ compilers extend the standard in some of these directions).

Comment: I did give "extern" a try, and it worked!  Solution is below for future readers:

#include <iostream>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl ringBell ( void )
 {
 std::cout << "\a" ;
 return 0 ;
 }

Answer (score 12):

All is working now :) To summarize your posts:

Write DLL in C++:

```
// Header
extern "C"
{   // Name in DLL will be "MyAdd" - but you won't be able to find parameters etc...
    __declspec(dllexport) int MyAdd(int a, int b);
}  
// Name will be with lot of prefixes but some other info is provided - IMHO better approach
__declspec(dllexport) int MyAdd2(int a, int b);

//.cpp Code
__declspec(dllexport) int MyAdd(int a, int b)
{   return a+b;
}
__declspec(dllexport) int MyAdd2(int a, int b)
{   return a+b;
}
```

Then you can use program link.exe to see real function name in dll. 
link.exe is for example in MSVC2010 here:

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.exe
```

use:

```
link /dump /exports yourFileName.dll
```

you see Something like:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
      1    0 00001040 ?MyAdd2@@YAHHH@Z = ?MyAdd2@@YAHHH@Z (int __cdecl MyAdd2(int,int))
      2    1 00001030 MyAdd = _MyAdd
```

Then in python you can import it as:

```
import ctypes

mc = ctypes.CDLL('C:\\testDll3.dll')

#mc.MyAdd2(1,2) # this Won't Work - name is different in dll
myAdd2 = getattr(mc,"?MyAdd2@@YAHHH@Z") #to find name use: link.exe /dump /exports fileName.dll 
print myAdd2(1,2)
#p1 = ctypes.c_int (1) #use rather c types
print mc[1](2,3) # use indexing - can be provided using link.exe

print mc.MyAdd(4,5)
print mc[2](6,7) # use indexing - can be provided using link.exe
```