# How to you call a function from a dll compiled by MSVC in python using ctypes?

Tags: c, python-3.x, visual-studio, dll, ctypes

I have some C code I'd like to wrap and call in python via ctypes.

```
//example.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example.h" //contains foo() declaration.

void foo(){
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Using the visual studio command line compiler I created a `.dll` file.

`cl /LD example.c` which created a file called `example.dll`.

I then attempt to call foo in python like this:

```
# example.py
import os
os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())
from ctypes import *

read_dll = WinDLL('example.dll')

foo = read_dll.foo #AttributeError: function 'foo' not found
```

And I get the Error Message: `AttributeError: function 'foo' not found` from the final line of `example.py`

Comment: You have to export the function with `dllexport`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269781/loading-dll-using-python-ctypes

Comment: @TonyTannous that worked, thank you.

Comment: Also, WinDLL is for `__stdcall` calling convention.  The default is `__cdecl` so use `CDLL`.  Note this won't matter on x64 where there is only one calling convention, but x86 will fail if you use the wrong one.